# Getting POCO classes in DbContext Generator

Tags: entity-framework, poco, dbcontext

Are the classes generated by DbContext Generator in EF4.1 considered as POCO and persistence ignorant?

If so, why am I getting an error: 
"**The entity or complex type '' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.**"?

This is my code:

```
return searchParam = from p in ent.PartnerProfiles
                  select new PartnerProfile
                  { 
                      PartnerName =  p.PartnerName
                  }.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can consider them to be POCOs and persistence ignorant, because they haven't got the wiring for notifying and tracking changes that the classes from an ObjectContext generator have.

That said, there are some conditions that EF requires for lazy loading to be enabled (`virtual` navigation properties) and in really persistent ignorant classes you won't find primitive primary or foreign key properties. The latter are not required, but very convenient at times (see [*foreign key associations*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/05/07/foreign-key-association-in-entity-framework-4.aspx)).

The error you get is by design. The reason for it is not well documented (as far as I know) but it probably has to do with the fact that EF only wants to track entities it has created itself, not the ones you generate in a projection. For many EF users this difference would not be obvious. I described some more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16359162/861716).

Comment: Thanks Gert. But if I want to eager load an associated class, how would I go about doing it? Using the include keyword would not work for me as I need to do extra filtering before I send it to my business layer.

Comment: That's a nuisance many other people have bumped into as well. There is a change request to enable filtering in `Include`, but I don't think it will be granted in EF 6. There are ways to work around this, but that would be a different question. Just try to find Q&As here at SO about this issue.